# Open MPI oversubscription failling

Tags: c, openmpi

I'm trying to run a MPI C program with more process than CPUs I have using the --oversubscribe flag. The problem is that even if I do that it returns  segmentation fault.

$ mpirun -np 8 --oversubscribe ./a

```
[0piero:68195] *** Process received signal ***
[0piero:68195] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[0piero:68195] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[0piero:68195] Failing at address: 0x7fd162194c80
[0piero:68185] *** Process received signal ***
[0piero:68185] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[0piero:68185] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[0piero:68185] Failing at address: 0x7ffbf42f13e0
[0piero:68185] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7ffbf88e2520]
[0piero:68185] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xdc2b0)[0x7ffbf48d42b0]
[0piero:68185] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94b43)[0x7ffbf8934b43]
[0piero:68185] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a00)[0x7ffbf89c6a00]
[0piero:68185] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mpirun noticed that process rank 5 with PID 0 on node 0piero exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).

I'm currently using the Open MPI 4.1.2.

Comment: Share the code for your program? Also more details about your platform might be relevant.

Comment: @DanBonachea the code don't have anything special ta all. I'm running on a ubuntu 22.04 quad core system